# List position changing

Tags: python

I have already asked the same question however I feel how I put it across is very vague. 
Basically I need to change:

```
data = 
[['15674' '24000' 'Manager' 'Gregory the 1st' 'John'], 
['15674' '24000' 'Manager' 'Gregory the 1st' 'John'], 
['15674' '24000' 'Manager' 'Gregory the 1st' 'John'],
['15674' '24000' 'Manager' 'Gregory the 1st' 'John']] 

data = [number, salary,position, othernames, firstname]
```

into:

```
data1= 
('John', 'Gregory the 1st',15674,'Manager',24000),
('John', 'Gregory the 1st',15674,'Manager',24000), 
('John', 'Gregory the 1st',15674,'Manager',24000,) 
('John', 'Gregory the 1st',15674,'Manager',24000)

data1 = (Firstname, othernames, number, position,salary)
```

I have repeated it to show that I could get a file with 100s of employees that need to have their information re arranged and printed out as a tuple in that order. All the items will have the same position e.g. `number[0]`, `salary[1]`, `position [2]` however the middle part which is other names could have several names so it wont have a definite position. The first name will however only be one item so could be found with `list1[-1]`.

```
def ex1 ():
    b= input("Please enter a file name to be opened: ")
    a = (b+".txt")    
    data =[]    
def employee(lanme, oname, num,title,salary):
    return (lanme, oname, num, title, salary)

def readfile(a):
    try:
        data =[]
        check = open(a, 'r')
        line =check.readlines()
        for items in line:
            breakup= items.split()
            data.append(breakup)
    except IOError as e :
        print("Failed to open", fileName)
readfile(a)
```

ex1()

Comment: Is your data actually in lists?  The first code block here isn't valid and would need some sort of parsing to take place before elements can be reordered.

Comment: I'm confused. Do these lists contain strings?

Comment: The data is retrieved from a text file that I have made. When I print them out after using a loop to store all the information as one big list as data = [['15674' '24000' 'Manager' 'Gregory the 1st' 'John'], 
['15674' '24000' 'Manager' 'Gregory the 1st' 'John'], 
['15674' '24000' 'Manager' 'Gregory the 1st' 'John'],
['15674' '24000' 'Manager' 'Gregory the 1st' 'John']] I need to take that information and rearrange it into the correct order and turn it into a tuple.

Comment: Do you mean a tuple of tuples or a list of tuples?

Comment: Is it really `'15674' '24000' 'Manager' 'Gregory the 1st' 'John'` or `'15674', '24000', 'Manager', 'Gregory the 1st', 'John'`?

Comment: the way the data variable it prints out exactly like that with a list within a list with every item a string. I think this is because it is from a file.

Comment: I need it to stored in a variable with each employee as a tuple. I can then do query on the information e.g. if name = "John" print the said tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is for list of lists, but it's simple.

```
data = ["15674 24000 Manager Gregory the 1st John", "15674 24000 Manager Gregory the 1st John",
        "15674 24000 Manager Gregory the 1st John", "15674 24000 Manager Gregory the 1st John"]

data1 = []

for items in data:
    splitNames = items.split()
    number, salary, position, first, des1, des2, last = splitNames
    data1.append([last, first + ' ' + des1 + ' ' + des2, number, position, salary])

for items in data1:
    print items
```

**Result:**

```
['John', 'Gregory the 1st', '15674', 'Manager', '24000']
['John', 'Gregory the 1st', '15674', 'Manager', '24000']
['John', 'Gregory the 1st', '15674', 'Manager', '24000']
['John', 'Gregory the 1st', '15674', 'Manager', '24000']
```

It's not the best solution , I wrote it that way so it will be easy to understand since it's basic manipulations.

**Tuple:**

if you want it to be list of tupels just rewrite this line:

```
data1.append(tuple([last, first + ' ' + des1 + ' ' + des2, number, position, salary]))
```

by using tuple() see an explanation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) from python docs.

**Result:**

```
('John', 'Gregory the 1st', '15674', 'Manager', '24000')
('John', 'Gregory the 1st', '15674', 'Manager', '24000')
('John', 'Gregory the 1st', '15674', 'Manager', '24000')
('John', 'Gregory the 1st', '15674', 'Manager', '24000')
```

**Adaption to your code:**

```
for items in line:
    breakup= items.split()
    number, salary, position, first, des1, des2, last = breakup
    data.append(tuple([last, first + ' ' + des1 + ' ' + des2, number, position, salary]))

print data
```

**Result:**

```
[('John', 'Gregory the 1st', '15674', 'Manager', '24000'), ('John', 'Gregory the 1st', '15674', 'Manager', '24000'), ('John', 'Gregory the 1st', '15674', 'Manager', '24000'), ('John', 'Gregory the 1st', '15674', 'Manager', '24000')]
```

Comment: You can also use a list comprehension.

Comment: @Maxime You are right, but since it's a basic question i thought it will be best to make it a readable and easy solution.

Comment: Thank you for the quick feedback however It doesn't work with my code which is incredibly annoying as the way the information is formatted is correctly but alas no dice.

Comment: @APD if you'll print your code, I will be able to adjust my answer to your code.

Comment: @APD i made an edit Adaption to your code, just copy paste it instead of your for statement... as you can see it results in list of tupels with the data as you wanted.

Comment: @kobiK thank you ever so much for sorting this out for me. Really appreciate it. HOpefully I can get the rest of it sorted without any issues.

Comment: @kobiK How would I adapt the des1 +des2 bit if I had more than two other names e.g. gregory the 1st of cambridge? Or is it always fixed

Comment: by that I mean I am not aware what the oname could be as some people only have two some have 7

Comment: If it's always at the same order, Data.....First, Last yo can split it to breakup list, First will be at place breakup[3]....breakup[N-2] and Last will be in breakup[N-1], now you can add all the values to one string, First = breakup[3] + .... + breakup[N-2]

Answer (score 3):

Reordering is easily accomplished if your input data is valid.

```
# First, Last, Number, Position, Salary
data = [(f,l,n,p,s) for n,s,p,l,f in data]
```

That will only work if your input value is a list of lists.  Your sample is not valid.